# iOS - How to make a backBarButtonItem also execute a custom function?

Tags: ios, backbarbuttonitem

I am an iOS development newbie. I am using the following code to set my backBarButtonItem -

```
UIBarButtonItem *temporaryBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];
temporaryBarButtonItem.title=@"Back";
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = temporaryBarButtonItem;
[temporaryBarButtonItem release];
```

I also want it to execute another function, apart from going back. Is that possible? Or do I need another button to save?

Comment: You can practically do that in your `viewDidDisapper` or `viewWillDisappear` method. If this view can only go back and doesn't present any views, then this should work.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you want to make it as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can practically do that in your `viewDidDisappear` or `viewWillDisappear` method.

If this view can only go back and doesn't present any views, then this should work.

However, if you plan on presenting a subview, modal view, go deeper in the navigation hierarchy, or do other view operations that will cause `viewDidDisapper` to get called, then you'll need to separate your back-button code logic somehow.

For instance if you will present a modal view from this view, you can check if `self.modalViewController` is nil, if it is then you have no modal view being present and can safely execute the back-button code. If it is not nil then you have a modal view present and should not execute back-button code. (`viewWillDisappear` should register the modal view controller as not-nil).

Answer (score 3):

Very simple, try this!

```
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(myCoolAction:)];
```

Then all you do is change myCoolAction: to an appropriate method in your view controller and handle it. Enjoy!

EDIT: Oh, if you want to use this for the backBarButtonItem, it won't work how you expect. The system will not call your target/actions for the backBarButtonItem. They get cleared once assigned to the backBarButtonItem.

One way to handle this is too hook up the your UINavigationController as a delegate. Then in your

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Method you can do some custom behavior there.

Comment: As @JoePasq pointed out you can also use the viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear. However those methods will get called under other circumstances other than Navigation, such as presentModalViewController: -> dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, this cannot be done with UIKit.

See the docs on `backBarButtonItem`:

> The target and action of the back bar button item you set should be
>   nil. The default value is a bar button item displaying the navigation
>   item’s title.

The work around is to specify a `leftBarButtonItem` and attach whatever custom behaviour you require by attaching a `@selector` target.

The tricky bit is the button's image itself. As you know the default is not a rectangular button. Rather it has a left side arrow shape. For this you'll need to set a custom image to make the button appear to be the default.

There's tons of resources to do that out there including this one to extract all the UIKit artwork:

https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor

Answer (score 1):

You can add UIBarButtonItem in xib and add handler event there.

Else create UIBarButtonItem with a custom view, which is an UIButton and add event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do something like this instead of using `viewDidDisappear` or `viewWillDisappear`.

Place this in `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonAction:)];
self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = NO;
```

Then you can create the method cancelButtonAction `cancelButtonAction` for your custom code and the back functionality like this:

```
- (void)cancelButtonAction:(id)sender {
    //Your custom code goes here...


    //This will perform the back functionality if using a Navigation Controller
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

**Note: this will end up using a rectangular button, without the arrow.**